Nested Java record in Hibernate criteria query
I cannot get hibernate citeria query working with nested Java Record because of: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at "."
I defined the Java record as the following:
public record RoomRecord(Long id, String identifier, int bedsNumber, int        Set<BedRecord> beds) {
    public record BedRecord(Long id, String identifier, Integer position) {}
}

The following is my criteria query:
CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<RoomRecord> criteria = builder.createQuery(RoomRecord.class).distinct(true);
Root<Room> root = criteria.from(Room.class);
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get(Room_.organization), organization));
criteria.select(builder.construct(RoomRecord.class, root.get(Room_.id),       root.get(Room_.identifier), root.get(Room_.floor), root.get(Room_.bedsNumber),
            root.get(Room_.virtualBedsNumber), root.get(Room_.beds)));`

